# Sliding vertical and horizontal markers matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have movable axes parallel to x or y specified by the user as vertical or horizontal markers.these markers need to be slidable and show the corresponding crossing points between the graph curves and the marker at whichever position it is set by the user.